# Cannot connect to webserver from outside LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, webserver, router, django

I am running the Django development server on a computer at home on ***0.0.0.0:80***.

I am also running an ***SSH*** service on port ***22***.
I have configured my router (Virgin Media Superhub 2 with external IP **80.80.80.80**) so that

1. My server has been provisioned the slot ***192.168.0.13***
2. I have
   forwarded ports 80 and 22 so that any external requests for those
   are pointed at 192.168.0.13:80/22.

I have configured no-ip suemphasized textch that the server is dynamically updating a no-ip url, ***foo.no-ip.biz***. I have also configured a Godaddy domain, ***foo.com*** with a CNAME DNS entry pointing to foo.no-ip.biz for all traffic from ***bar.foo.com***.

When I try and access either ***bar.foo.com*** or ***foo.no-ip.biz*** or **80.80.80.80** or ***192.168.0.13*** from a laptop in my LAN using Google Chrome, I can access everything just fine, and see my website.

However, when I try and access it from *outside* my LAN, the connection just times out. This occurs on all of the above addresses minutes the 192... one.

I can SSH using any of the addresses, and I can also see that both port 22 and 80 are open using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ so what could be wrong? I'm sorry if you must get loads of questions like this, but most of the examples I've seen have different situations i.e. they haven't forwarded ports or something like that. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have a virgin media business accoutn as the home user one can not be configured for static ips

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a port forwarding on your router and set it so that port 80 points to the right ip address and to port 80. Note if you have external management of your router enabled on port 80 too, you have to disable this.

If you have more than one router/modem that does port forwarding, make sure you set a portforwarding on every device. Also, if your expernal ip changes, you need to do an ipconfig /flushdns to get the new ipaddress.

If things aren't working from outside, make sure you can ping the address and that you get the right ipaddress.

Comment: Like I say I have already enabled port forwarding on my router
http://i.stack.imgur.com/cAyCK.png, and I can see the ports are open from a website online.
I only have one router, so that can't be the problem.
Interestingly though, when I ping foo.bar.com from outside my LAN it comes back with this address. cpc20-acto3-2-0-cust165.4-2.cable.virginm.net I am on virgin, but I don't understand what the address means

Answer (score 0):

Telnetting to port 80 of:

```
cpc20-acto3-2-0-cust165.4-2.cable.virginm.net (the name your ISP gives your IP address)
```

I should be getting a connection response, but I just get:

```
Trying 81.101.5.166...
telnet: connect to address 81.101.5.166: Network is unreachable
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

This tells me that the port isn't open.  While it looks as though you are forwarding OK, there may be a firewall setting that has the port closed.  Find that and open it and you should be in business.